# My Flutter app stuck in White Screen! after using google_mobile_ads

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-layout, flutter-test

**My app stuck in White Screen!**
Need a **help** on ''AdMov''
I have installed google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.0
& Followed the Whole Documentation according to the
"https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-ads-in-flutter#3"
There shown no error in my app but after install My app stuck in White Screen!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post logs from `Run` tab if you are using Android Studio

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NKjza3EN

Comment: This is my Run Debug Console

Comment: You are getting null pointer exception somewhere which is working in debug but it will not work in release mode. Check what you have done which is getting null